# Add random values to multiple lists

Tags: python

```
import string
import random
    
string_pool = ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
names = ["Ironman", "Thor", "Spiderman"]

def func1(a):
    d = []
    for b in a:
        continue
    for c in range(5):
        c += 1
        d += random.choice(string_pool)
    return print("{} : ".format(b) , d)

func1(names)
```

I expect the result of this code is below

```
Ironman : ["X", "X", "Y", "Z", "X"]
Thor : ["Y", "X", "Z", "Z", "X"]
Spiderman : ["Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "X"]
```

but, the result is

```
Spiderman : ["Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "X"]
```

only spiderman... what should i change in my code? Thank you!

Comment: Check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  Your program has several strange statements that strongly suggest that you need to repeat your instruction on basic Python statements and data types.  It is also time to learn how to debug a program.  Your post throws several guesses into a file, and then you seem lost as to how you get output other than what you wanted.  This says that you have a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for b in a:
        continue
```

Not sure what you expect this line to do.

What it *actually* does is execute a `for` loop in which nothing happens. At the beginning of each iteration of a `for` loop, the loop control variable (in this case `b`) gets assigned the value of the next element in the iterable (in this case, `a`.

In this case, the loop would iterate three times:

```
b = 'Ironman'
b = 'Thor'
b = 'Spiderman'
```

and since the interior of the loop is empty (just the `continue` statement, which means "jump back to the top of the loop immediately and go to the next iteration"), nothing happens.

Now, once the loop finishes iterating, the variable `b` isn't cleared or reset. The last thing assigned to it was the last element of `a`, which is the string `'spiderman'`.

---

Did you mean to do:

```
for b in a:
    d = []
    for c in range(5):
        d += random.choice(string_pool)
    print("{} : ".format(b) , d)
```

Note how the rest of the function is *inside* the `for` loop.

Comment: return print() is fishy here.

Comment: @sonulohani Thanks for the heads-up. Shouldn't have just copied the code without examining it. I've cleaned it up.

Comment: Now its just `d = [random.choice(string_pool) for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you're trying to do here. But here is the code which will print output for all the names:

```
import random
    
string_pool = ["W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
names = ["Ironman", "Thor", "Spiderman"]

def func1(a):
    for b in a:
        d = []
        for _ in range(5):
            d += random.choice(string_pool)
        print("{} : ".format(b) , d)

func1(names)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this code. but in this case, the right side(list of random letters) is not controlled in five words..

Comment: Is it because I get the list of 5 characters in the output. Could you please paste this updated code.

Comment: Now it is working! thank you. Could you help me one more plz. I want to use b and d outside of the function. how can i handle this problem?